# Bukkit Custom Prefix plugin doesn't work with Essentials

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a plugin that will have ranks in the near future, but I decided to get past prefixes first. I have this code:

```
    Essentials ess = (Essentials) Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Essentials");
    User user = ess.getUserMap().getUser(p.getName());
    //nickname
    String nick = user.getDisplayName();
    String prisoner = ColourMsg("&5<<&bPrisoner&5>>&r>" + " <");

    p.setDisplayName(prisoner + nick);
```

For some reason, this code doesn't work! It only displays the nickname, and not the prefix (I would expect it to display both). Also, the only error message I get is from essentials chat, which isn't needed for my plugin and /nick still works.

If anyone can help, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Error message? How does result differ from expected result?

Comment: Where is this code executed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Essentials for that (Essentials is a bad plugin anyway, since 1.8).
You can simply use scoreboard prefixes/suffix in the PlayerJoinEvent to set the tags.

```
 Scoreboard sb = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
 Objective ob = sb.registerNewObjective("objName", "dummy");

    public void onEnable() {
        // Set Display slot
        ob.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.PLAYER_LIST);
    }

    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        // Delay a task
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (e.getPlayer().hasPermission("tags.example")) {
                    sb.registerNewTeam("Example");
                    Team team = sb.getTeam("Example");
                    team.setPrefix(ChatColor.RED + "[Example]");
                    team.addEntry(e.getPlayer().getName());
                } else if (e.getPlayer().hasPermission("tags.otherTag")) {
                    sb.registerNewTeam("OtherTag");
                    Team team = sb.getTeam("OtherTag");
                    team.setPrefix(ChatColor.GREEN + "[OtherTag]");
                    team.addEntry(e.getPlayer().getName());
                }
            }
        }, 20 * 1); // The 1 is the number of seconds to delay, 1 is fine
    }
```